# Is there any Java/JDBC code analytics validation tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I work with very huge and old project. My task is to find all JDBC connections not initialized in try block. Also i have to find all not closed (or closed in wrong order) result sets, statements and connections. Is there any code validation tool to search that kind of bad practises (may be integrated with Eclispe, but it is not required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote small script to validate source code. Feel free to modify/use:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class DbValidator
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    if (args.length < 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    Path lvRootPath = Paths.get(args[0]);

    findAndParse(lvRootPath);
  }

  private static void findAndParse(Path pmPath)
  {
    File lvDir = pmPath.toFile();

    if (!lvDir.exists())
    {
      return;
    }

    File[] lvFiles = lvDir.listFiles();

    for (File file : lvFiles)
    {
      if (file.isDirectory())
      {
        findAndParse(file.toPath());
      }
      else
      {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".java"))
          parseFile(file.toPath());
      }
    }
  }

  private static void parseFile(Path pmPath)
  {
    // System.out.println("#Validating file: " + pmPath);
    try
    {
      List<String> lvLines = Files.readAllLines(pmPath,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      Map<String, Integer> lvConNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // map var-name : level;
      Map<String, Integer> lvPsNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      Map<String, Integer> lvRsNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      List<Integer> lvTryBlocks = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // opened try blocks
      int lvLevel = 0;
      int lvLineIdx = 1;

      for (String line : lvLines)
      {
        lvLevel = checkLevel(line,lvLevel);
        closeTryBlocks(lvTryBlocks,lvLevel);
        checkIfConectionGetter(lvTryBlocks,line,lvLineIdx,pmPath);

        line = line.trim();

        if (line.startsWith("Connection"))
        {
          String lvName = line.replaceFirst("Connection\\s","").replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*(.)*+","");
          lvConNames.put(lvName,lvLevel);
          lvLineIdx++;
          continue;
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("PreparedStatement"))
        {
          String lvName = line.replaceFirst("PreparedStatement\\s","").replaceAll("\\s=\\s*(.)*+","");
          lvPsNames.put(lvName,lvLevel);
          lvLineIdx++;
          continue;
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("ResultSet"))
        {
          String lvName = line.replaceFirst("ResultSet\\s","").replaceAll("\\s=\\s*(.)*+","");
          lvRsNames.put(lvName,lvLevel);
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("try"))
        {
          lvTryBlocks.add(lvLevel);
          lvLineIdx++;
          continue;
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("StreamUtils.closeQuietly"))
        {
          String[] lvElements = line.replaceAll("StreamUtils.closeQuietly\\(","").replaceAll("\\);","").split(",");

          boolean lvWasPs = false;
          boolean lvWasCon = false;

          for (String element : lvElements)
          {
            element = element.trim();

            if (lvPsNames.get(element) != null)
            {
              lvPsNames.remove(element);
              if (lvWasCon)
              {
                System.out.println("#######################################################################");
                System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + lvLineIdx);
                System.out.println("#Wrong closing order");
                System.out.println("#######################################################################");
              }

              lvWasPs = true;
            }
            else if (lvRsNames.get(element) != null)
            {
              lvRsNames.remove(element);

              if (lvWasCon || lvWasPs)
              {
                System.out.println("#######################################################################");
                System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + lvLineIdx);
                System.out.println("#Wrong closing order");
                System.out.println("#######################################################################");
              }
            }
            else if (lvConNames.get(element) != null)
            {
              lvConNames.remove(element);
              lvWasCon = true;
            }
          }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> lvConNamesTmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>(lvConNames);
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : lvConNamesTmp.entrySet())
        {
          Integer lvValue = entry.getValue();

          if (lvValue > lvLevel)
          {
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");
            System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + lvLineIdx);
            System.out.println("#Not closed Connection");
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");
            lvConNames.remove(entry.getKey());
          }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> lvPsNamesTmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>(lvPsNames);
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : lvPsNamesTmp.entrySet())
        {
          Integer lvValue = entry.getValue();

          if (lvValue > lvLevel)
          {
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");
            System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + lvLineIdx);
            System.out.println("#Not closed PreparedStatement");
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");

            lvPsNamesTmp.remove(entry.getKey());
          }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> lvRsNamesTmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>(lvRsNames);
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : lvRsNamesTmp.entrySet())
        {
          Integer lvValue = entry.getValue();

          if (lvValue > lvLevel)
          {
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");
            System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + lvLineIdx);
            System.out.println("#Not closed ResultSet");
            System.out.println("#######################################################################");

            lvRsNames.remove(entry.getKey());
          }
        }

        ++lvLineIdx;
      }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // System.out.println("#Parsing error at file: " + pmPath);
      // e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void checkIfConectionGetter(List<Integer> pmTryBlocks, String pmLine, int pmLineIndex, Path pmPath)
  {
    if (pmLine.indexOf("DbUtils.getConnection") != -1 && pmTryBlocks.isEmpty())
    {
      System.out.println("#######################################################################");
      System.out.println("#!!! Warning at file \"" + pmPath + "\" at line: " + pmLineIndex);
      System.out.println("#!!! Connection initialize outisde of try block");
      System.out.println("#######################################################################");
    }
  }

  private static void closeTryBlocks(List<Integer> pmTryBlocks, int pmLevel)
  {
    int lvIndexOf = pmTryBlocks.indexOf(new Integer(pmLevel));

    if (lvIndexOf != -1)
    {
      pmTryBlocks.remove(lvIndexOf);
    }
  }

  private static int checkLevel(String pmLine, int pmCurrentLevel)
  {
    // check level
    int lvIndexOfStart = -1;
    int lvIndexOfEnd = -1;
    int lvLevel = pmCurrentLevel;

    String lvLineTmp = pmLine;

    do
    {
      if (lvLineTmp.indexOf("}") != -1)
      {
        lvLineTmp = lvLineTmp.replaceFirst("\\}","");
        lvLevel--;
      }
      else if (lvLineTmp.indexOf("{") != -1)
      {
        lvLineTmp = lvLineTmp.replaceFirst("\\{","");
        lvLevel++;
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }

    }
    while (true);

    return lvLevel;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a static analysis tool. I think [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) will probably help here, but there is also [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) (and to a lesser extent [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)).

Two FingBugs checks in particular may be of use:

- [Method may fail to close database resource](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE)
- [Method may fail to close database resource on exception](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE_EXCEPTION_PATH)

Comment: I use findbug actually. Is there any trick to filter findbug report to show only problems with JDBC?

Comment: Probably - there is a Findbugs GUI which lets you filter, I think.

Comment: Findbug didn't notice this one for example:

    finally
    {
      StreamUtils.closeQuietly(lvConnection,lvResult,lvStatement);
    }